# Plot power law fit to degree distribution in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I created a directed graph in igraph,

```
ba_game_graph <- sample_pa(10000, power = 1, m = NULL, out.dist = NULL, out.seq = NULL,
  out.pref = FALSE, zero.appeal = 1, directed = TRUE,
  algorithm = c("psumtree"), start.graph = NULL)
```

Got its degree distribution

```
ba_game_deg_dist_tot <- degree_distribution(ba_game_graph, cumulative = FALSE, mode = c("total"))
```

Fit the power law

```
ba_game_plaw <- fit_power_law(ba_game_deg_dist_tot, implementation = c("plfit"), force.continuous = FALSE)
```

Now i want to plot the histogram of degree distribution and the power law curve on top of it. how do i do it?

```
hist(ba_game_deg_dist_tot, pch=20, breaks=25, prob=TRUE, main="")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is four years after the fact, but I think this is probably what you want:

```r
# plot the degree distribution on a log-log plot
plot(ba_game_deg_dist_tot,
     log = "xy",
     xlab = "Node Degree",
     ylab = "Probability")

# add the fitted power law line; the exponent value comes from alpha, part of
# the output of the fit.power.law() function. 
lines(seq(ba_game_deg_dist_tot), 
      seq(ba_game_deg_dist_tot)^-ba_game_plaw$alpha, 
      col="#b00606")
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Given the p-value (in the list produced by the power.law.fit() function), the model is a plausible fit to the data. But, if I understand things correctly, you'd need to confirm this by comparing the fit to other kinds of distributions which might be a better fit. Not sure how to do this--but maybe this gets you a bit closer.